# setState creating indexes while updating property

Tags: reactjs

Am new to React, am facing one issue while updating setState()
and in console is showing error as attached image.

```html
 <input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              id="firstName"
              placeholder="First Name"
              onChange={e => {
                this.handleInput(e);
              }}
              required
            />
```

```js
handleInput = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    let formErrors = FORM_ERRORS;

    switch (name) {
      case "firstName":
        formErrors.firstName =
          value.length < 3 && value.length >= 0
            ? "Minimum 3 characters required"
            : "";
        break;
      case "mobile":
        formErrors.mobile =
          value.length < 10 && value.length >= 0 ? "Invalid mobile number" : "";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    console.log("on handle name and value", name, value);
    this.setState(state => (state[name] = value));
    this.setState(state => (state.formErrors[name] = formErrors[name]));
    console.log("on handle ", this.state);
  };
```

[image]

and in console is showing error as attached image. am not sure why this is happening 
thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you want `this.setState({ [name]: value })` and `this.setState({ formErrors: { [name] : formErrors[name] } })`.

Comment: Please describe your expected and the actual results, include any error messages as suggested in the question wizard.

Comment: const FORM_ERRORS = {
  firstName: "",
  mobile: ""
};

const EDIT_PROFILE_FORM = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  mobile: "",
  displayPicture: null,
  resume: null,
  formErrors: FORM_ERRORS
};
this is my state object

Comment: It seems you have several misconceptions about component-state-management in React. I suggest you spend some time with the documentation and maybe look for some good tutorials: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not using `setState` correctly.

If you replace these two lines:

```js
    this.setState(state => (state[name] = value));
    this.setState(state => (state.formErrors[name] = formErrors[name]));
```

With these lines:

```js
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    this.setState(state =>
      { formErrors: { ...state.formErrors, [name]: formErrors[name] } }
    );
```

It should work, although I can't be certain, since you haven't shared the shape your component's state should have.

Here's an example of a simple class component using local state (including 'resetting' the state):

```js
const initialState = { count: 0 }

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  // here I pass a function to this.setState
  increment() {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ count: state.count + 1 })
    );
  }
  decrement() {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ count: state.count - 1 })
    );
  }

  // here I pass an object to this.setState
  setToFive() {
    this.setState({ count: 5 });
  }

  // to reset the entire state, I pass the initialState
  // object to this.setState
  reset() {
    this.setState(initialState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <h2>Count: {this.state.count}</h2>
        <p><button onClick={() => this.increment()}>Increment Counter</button></p>
        <p><button onClick={() => this.decrement()}>Decrement Counter</button></p>
        <p><button onClick={() => this.setToFive()}>Set Counter to 5</button></p>
        <p><button onClick={() => this.reset()}>Reset State</button></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note: If you're using a more recent version of React (>= v16.8), you can also use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to manage state. This would allow you to use a function component rather than a class component, but you may want to master `setState` with class components first.

Comment: what is the best way of reset the state?

Comment: See the snippet I added for examples of component state management, including resetting the state to its initial values.

Comment: this.setState({ formErrors: { [name]: formErrors[name] } });
the above statement is re-initializing the formErrors. due to which am loosing the existing properties and it has only one property. i want to update only one property on onChange()

Comment: i tried like this.setState({ formErrors[name]: formErrors[name] }); but it is giving error @tex